# SWI-Prolog - show long list

Tags: swi-prolog, prolog-toplevel

I'm using SWI-Prolog and I'm trying to print a list but if the list has more than 9 items - it look like that -

```
[1, 15, 8, 22, 5, 19, 12, 25, 3|...]
```

is there a way to show the whole list?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Have a look at: http://www.swi-prolog.org/FAQ/AllOutput.html

The simple solution is to type **w** after the answer is given, i.e.:

```
?- n_queens_problem(10,X).
X = [1, 3, 6, 8, 10, 5, 9, 2, 4|...] [write]
X = [1, 3, 6, 8, 10, 5, 9, 2, 4, 7]
```

After you have pressed the "w"-key "[write]" is displayed at the end and the full solution appears in the next line.

Comment: This doesn't work if prolog is only returning one answer.

Comment: If the query succeeds deterministically, you can simply write: `?- solution(S) ; true.`, i.e., simply append `; true` to introduce a choice-point. Then, you also get the opportunity to press `w`.

Comment: you simply type w in the output

Answer (score 16):

I've found two ways.

---

1.

```
?- set_prolog_flag(answer_write_options,[max_depth(0)]).
true.
```

Then do your command that is printing a truncated list.

([set_prolog_flag documentation](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=set_prolog_flag/2))

---

2.

```
?- atom_chars(goodbye_prolog, X) ; true.
```

([AllOutput documentation](http://www.swi-prolog.org/FAQ/AllOutput.html))

Put `; true.` at the end of the call that results in a long list. Then push the <kbd>w</kbd> key on your keyboard. The result is:

```
?- sudoku([_,_,2,3,_,_,_,_,_,_,_,_,3,4,_,_], Solution); true.
Solution = [4, 1, 2, 3, 2, 3, 4, 1, 1|...] [write]
Solution = [4, 1, 2, 3, 2, 3, 4, 1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 4, 1, 2] ;
true.
```

Answer (score 4):

If prolog returns only one answer, you can make it wait by typing "; true." after the predicate. Then, if you press "w", you will get to see the whole list as written in the doc : http://www.swi-prolog.org/FAQ/AllOutput.html

Answer (score 2):

```
?- createListSomehow(List), print(List), nl.
```

will do it neatly enough.  That's what I do.

Variation:

```
?- use_module(library(pprint)). %load a library to do pretty-printing
?- createListSomehow(List), print_term(List,[]), nl.
```

The `[]` argument to `print_term` is an (empty) list of options.  For more information, [see documentation](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=prolog_pretty_print%3Aprint_term/2).

Answer (score 1):

If you want that SWI-Prolog will show the whole list by default you can add this line to your [init file](https://www.swi-prolog.org/FAQ/PlInitialisation.html):

```
:- set_prolog_flag(answer_write_options,[max_depth(0)]).
```

You can modify the init file easily from the GUI (Settings => User init file).