# PROLOG, meaning of

Tags: prolog, semantics

I don't understand what is the meaning of

```
[sopio|...], [...|...]|...
```

in the result of
`?- findall([X,Y], indirectowner(X, Y), L).`:

```
L = [[sopio, badri], [temur, badri], [temur, leila], [badri, anuki], [badri, tamar], [tamar, ioseb], [sopio, anuki], [sopio|...], [...|...]|...].
```

I have dafined following facts:

```
owner(sopio,badri).
owner(temur,badri).
owner(temur,leila).
owner(badri,anuki).
owner(badri,tamar).
owner(tamar,ioseb).
```

and clauses:

```
indirectowner(X,Z) :-
owner(X,Z).
indirectowner(X,Z) :-
owner(X,Y), owner(Y,Z).
```

Comment: You might want to have a look at [SWI Prolog show long list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8231762/swi-prolog-show-long-list)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is abbreviated in order to avoid having too much output on the screen. 
In SWI-Prolog you can press `w` after the query to write the whole answer but for your query you need `YOURquery  ; true.` because it is deterministic and for the `w` to be accepted it needs a non-deterministic query. 
You can also change the behaviour using Prolog flags.

Comment: Better: `; false.`!

Comment: why is that better?

Comment: Because it does not make a query that otherwise fails succeed! In other words, it does not increase the set of solutions. A shorter version: `;0=1.`