# Towers of Hanoi using Lists Prolog

Tags: list, prolog, towers-of-hanoi

I know that there is already sample programs floating around that cover this, but I need to do the towers of hanoi with 6 discs a specific way for an assignment and I'm having trouble. Code I currently have is below:

```
s([],[],[]).

initial(s([1,2,3,4,5,6], [], [])).

goal(s([],[],[1,2,3,4,5,6])).
```

I also have 26 lines of code to verify valid states, however I tested that code on it's own and it works, the issue I'm having is creating the code to move the discs from stack to stack. An example of what I'm trying to do along with an example query is below:

```
changeState((s([A | B],[],[])), s([C], [D], [])) :- C is B, D is A.
?- changeState((s([1,2,3,4,5,6],[],[])), s([2,3,4,5,6], [1], [])).
```

So this would be the very beginning, where all 6 plates are on the first stack, and I want to move the top plate to the second stack. Essentially, I want to be able to remove the first element from a list, and add it to another list, whether it is empty or not.

**Edits:**

Got what I needed above working, now I just need help fixing the traverse predicate. Entire code is below:

```
%Post A, Post B, Post C
s([],[],[]).

initial(s([1,2,3,4,5,6], [], [])).

goal(s([],[],[1,2,3,4,5,6])).

valid([], _).
valid([H|_], X) :-
    X < H.

changeState((s([A|T1], T2, T3)), s(T1, [A|T2], T3)) :-
    valid(T2, A).
changeState((s([A|T1], T2, T3)), s(T1, T2, [A|T3])) :-
    valid(T3, A).
changeState(s(T1, [A|T2], [B|T3]), s(T1, T2, [A,B|T3])) :-
    valid(A,B).
changeState(s([A|T1], T2, [B|T3]), s([B,A|T1], T2, T3)) :-
    valid(B, A).
changeState(s(T1, [A|T2], [B|T3]), s(T1, [B,A|T2], T3)) :-
    valid(B, A).
changeState(s([A|T1], [B|T2], T3), s(T1, [A,B|T2], T3)) :-
    valid(A,B).
changeState(s([A|T1], [B|T2], T3), s([B,A|T1], T2, T3)) :-
    valid(B,A).
changeState(s([A|T1], T2, [B|T3]), s(T1, T2, [A,B|T3])) :-
    valid(A,B).
changeState(s(T1, [A|T2], T3), s(T1, T2, [A|T3])) :-
    valid(T3, A).
changeState(s(T1, [A|T2], T3), s([A|T1], T2, T3)) :-
    valid(T1, A).
changeState(s(T1, T2, [A|T3]), s(T1, [A|T2], T3)) :-
    valid(T2, A).
changeState(s(T1, T2, [A|T3]), s([A|T1], T2, T3)) :-
    valid(T1, A).

traverse(StartNode,Sol,_) :- goal(StartNode), Sol = [StartNode].
traverse(StartNode,Sol,Visit) :- changeState(StartNode, NextNode),
       not(member(NextNode, Visit)),
       traverse(NextNode, PartialSol, [NextNode|Visit]),
       Sol = [StartNode | PartialSol].
```

When I run this query:

```
?- traverse((s([1,2,3,4,5,6], [], [])), Sol, s([1,2,3,4,5,6], [], [])).
```

I get this output: [image: output]

I've left it running after I get those responses for about 10 minutes and it still doesn't produce new ones so it's just continuing to run over and over again. As mentioned above, the point of the program is to solve the Towers of Hanoi problem with 6 discs using Lists. For those not familiar with Towers of Hanoi, you essentially need to move all discs from the first stack, to the last 3rd stack. You can only move 1 disc at a time, and you cannot place a larger disc on-top of a smaller disc. So you start with (s([1,2,3,4,5,6], [], [])) with each list representing Stack A, Stack B, Stack C respectively, and the goal is to end with (s([], [], [1,2,3,4,5,6])). I manually ran through an entire solution (63 moves) through the changeState predicates and all transitions were accepted, so the issue is with the transverse predicate. The transverse predicate is meant to show all steps that lead up to the solution, and all possible solutions. It's also meant to stop cycles, so that it's not just swapping the same 2 discs over and over again. Can't quite figure out what's wrong with my predicates thats causing me to get this output, I'm still fairly new to prolog, so I would appreciate any help!

Comment: your full [mcve]? your sample query? the desired results? the actual results? your specific question?

Comment: The original question I posted was answered, but I needed help with the next step so I made edits in a response to another person's answer and assumed they would answer soon, which is why I didn't explain the edits. Since he's responded and it didn't solve my issue, I adjusted the edits so that it's clear to everyone what it is I need now.

Comment: your "output" picture indicates that you got 12 solutions and pressed `;` 12 times to request the next solution. Is this what happened? Are you saying that after pressing `;` for the 12th time you've waited 10 minutes without receiving the next solution?

Comment: As I mentioned, this is meant to solve the towers of hanoi puzzle and show all of the steps required to solve the problem, meaning at the end, it should show (s([], [], [1,2,3,4,5,6], and show every transition made to get to that solution from the starting point, which as I mentioned is (s([1,2,3,4,5,6], [], [])). The goal output is never shown. That output there is just the same thing over and over and over again 12 times. After the 12th time, it is still running through the predicates, but I've left it running for 10+ minutes and it has yet to provide any additional output.

Comment: So you did get 12 solutions for your query. Are you sure they were wrong? Instead of pressing `;`, press `w` one time, then press `.`. Copy the result and post it here.

Comment: @Intellects: that is because Prolog typically "cuts off" the notation of a list. In reality these elements *exist*, but if this generates a list of 100k elements, then it will, by default, not "fill" your screen with noise.

Comment: It provides too much output for me to paste it all, but it provides the correct output when I press w. So the output that it was showing me, was that just the start of a solution, but it can't show the entire solution unless I press w?

Comment: @Intellects: it can, you can also use `traverse(..,S,...),print(S)` to print `S`, in that case it will print the entire list to the STDOUT.

Comment: The other lists are just other ways to solve the puzzle.

Comment: Ah okay, I didn't know that, I've never really dealt with solutions this large so I didn't know it wouldn't just print it all out. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use *unification* here instead of `is/2` (which is typically used to evaluate expressions).

For example we can define a move from the first tower to the second tower, given the second tower is empty:

```
changeState((s([A|T1],[], T3)), s(T1, [A], T3)).
```

or we can move an element to the second tower that is non-empty, given the top of the stack is an element that is larger:

```
changeState(s([A|T1], [B|T2], T3), s(T1, [A,B|T2], T3)) :-
    A < B.
```

The above will result in a total of 12 rules: 3 sources, times 2 destinations times 2 possibilities (empty destination, versus non-empty destination). This is not very elegant. We can construct a helper predicate that checks if the destination stack is valid, with:

```
valid_stack([], _).
valid_stack([H|_], X) :-
    X < H.
```

so then we can compress the two rules above into:

```
changeState((s([A|T1], T2, T3)), s(T1, [A|T2], T3)) :-
    valid_stack(T2, A).
```

This will thus result in six rules: three sources, and two destinations.

We thus no longer need to validate the moves, since if the `changeState` succeeds, then the proposed move is possible *given* the original state was valid.

This is not the full solution however (I leave the rest as an exercise). You will need a mechanism that enumerates over the possible moves, and makes sure that you do not end up in loops (like moving a disc constantly between two towers).

After using the `traverse/3` predicate, we obtain a list of moves to the goal:

```
?- traverse(s([1,2,3,4,5,6], [], []), S, [s([1,2,3,4,5,6], [], [])]).
S = [s([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], [], []), s([2, 3, 4, 5, 6], [1], []), s([3, 4, 5, 6], [1], [2]), s([1, 3, 4, 5|...], [], [2]), s([3, 4, 5|...], [], [1, 2]), s([4, 5|...], [3], [1, 2]), s([1|...], [3], [2]), s([...|...], [...|...], [...]), s(..., ..., ...)|...] [write]
S = [s([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], [], []), s([2, 3, 4, 5, 6], [1], []), s([3, 4, 5, 6], [1], [2]), s([1, 3, 4, 5, 6], [], [2]), s([3, 4, 5, 6], [], [1, 2]), s([4, 5, 6], [3], [1, 2]), s([1, 4, 5, 6], [3], [2]), s([4, 5, 6], [1, 3], [2]), s([2, 4, 5, 6], [1, 3], []), s([1, 2, 4, 5, 6], [3], []), s([2, 4, 5, 6], [3], [1]), s([4, 5, 6], [2, 3], [1]), s([1, 4, 5, 6], [2, 3], []), s([4, 5, 6], [1, 2, 3], []), s([5, 6], [1, 2, 3], [4]), s([1, 5, 6], [2, 3], [4]), s([5, 6], [2, 3], [1, 4]), s([2, 5, 6], [3], [1, 4]), s([1, 2, 5, 6], [3], [4]), s([2, 5, 6], [1, 3], [4]), s([5, 6], [1, 3], [2, 4]), s([1, 5, 6], [3], [2, 4]), s([5, 6], [3], [1, 2, 4]), s([3, 5, 6], [], [1, 2, 4]), s([1, 3, 5, 6], [], [2, 4]), s([3, 5, 6], [1], [2, 4]), s([2, 3, 5, 6], [1], [4]), s([1, 2, 3, 5, 6], [], [4]), s([2, 3, 5, 6], [], [1, 4]), s([3, 5, 6], [2], [1, 4]), s([1, 3, 5, 6], [2], [4]), s([3, 5, 6], [1, 2], [4]), s([5, 6], [1, 2], [3, 4]), s([1, 5, 6], [2], [3, 4]), s([5, 6], [2], [1, 3, 4]), s([2, 5, 6], [], [1, 3, 4]), s([1, 2, 5, 6], [], [3, 4]), s([2, 5, 6], [1], [3, 4]), s([5, 6], [1], [2, 3, 4]), s([1, 5, 6], [], [2, 3, 4]), s([5, 6], [], [1, 2, 3, 4]), s([6], [5], [1, 2, 3, 4]), s([1, 6], [5], [2, 3, 4]), s([6], [1, 5], [2, 3, 4]), s([2, 6], [1, 5], [3, 4]), s([1, 2, 6], [5], [3, 4]), s([2, 6], [5], [1, 3, 4]), s([6], [2, 5], [1, 3, 4]), s([1, 6], [2, 5], [3, 4]), s([6], [1, 2, 5], [3, 4]), s([3, 6], [1, 2, 5], [4]), s([1, 3, 6], [2, 5], [4]), s([3, 6], [2, 5], [1, 4]), s([2, 3, 6], [5], [1, 4]), s([1, 2, 3, 6], [5], [4]), s([2, 3, 6], [1, 5], [4]), s([3, 6], [1, 5], [2, 4]), s([1, 3, 6], [5], [2, 4]), s([3, 6], [5], [1, 2, 4]), s([6], [3, 5], [1, 2, 4]), s([1, 6], [3, 5], [2, 4]), s([6], [1, 3, 5], [2, 4]), s([2, 6], [1, 3, 5], [4]), s([1, 2, 6], [3, 5], [4]), s([2, 6], [3, 5], [1, 4]), s([6], [2, 3, 5], [1, 4]), s([1, 6], [2, 3, 5], [4]), s([6], [1, 2, 3, 5], [4]), s([4, 6], [1, 2, 3, 5], []), s([1, 4, 6], [2, 3, 5], []), s([4, 6], [2, 3, 5], [1]), s([2, 4, 6], [3, 5], [1]), s([1, 2, 4, 6], [3, 5], []), s([2, 4, 6], [1, 3, 5], []), s([4, 6], [1, 3, 5], [2]), s([1, 4, 6], [3, 5], [2]), s([4, 6], [3, 5], [1, 2]), s([3, 4, 6], [5], [1, 2]), s([1, 3, 4, 6], [5], [2]), s([3, 4, 6], [1, 5], [2]), s([2, 3, 4, 6], [1, 5], []), s([1, 2, 3, 4, 6], [5], []), s([2, 3, 4, 6], [5], [1]), s([3, 4, 6], [2, 5], [1]), s([1, 3, 4, 6], [2, 5], []), s([3, 4, 6], [1, 2, 5], []), s([4, 6], [1, 2, 5], [3]), s([1, 4, 6], [2, 5], [3]), s([4, 6], [2, 5], [1, 3]), s([2, 4, 6], [5], [1, 3]), s([1, 2, 4, 6], [5], [3]), s([2, 4, 6], [1, 5], [3]), s([4, 6], [1, 5], [2, 3]), s([1, 4, 6], [5], [2, 3]), s([4, 6], [5], [1, 2, 3]), s([6], [4, 5], [1, 2, 3]), s([1, 6], [4, 5], [2, 3]), s([6], [1, 4, 5], [2, 3]), s([2, 6], [1, 4, 5], [3]), s([1, 2, 6], [4, 5], [3]), s([2, 6], [4, 5], [1, 3]), s([6], [2, 4, 5], [1, 3]), s([1, 6], [2, 4, 5], [3]), s([6], [1, 2, 4, 5], [3]), s([3, 6], [1, 2, 4, 5], []), s([1, 3, 6], [2, 4, 5], []), s([3, 6], [2, 4, 5], [1]), s([2, 3, 6], [4, 5], [1]), s([1, 2, 3, 6], [4, 5], []), s([2, 3, 6], [1, 4, 5], []), s([3, 6], [1, 4, 5], [2]), s([1, 3, 6], [4, 5], [2]), s([3, 6], [4, 5], [1, 2]), s([6], [3, 4, 5], [1, 2]), s([1, 6], [3, 4, 5], [2]), s([6], [1, 3, 4, 5], [2]), s([2, 6], [1, 3, 4, 5], []), s([1, 2, 6], [3, 4, 5], []), s([2, 6], [3, 4, 5], [1]), s([6], [2, 3, 4, 5], [1]), s([1, 6], [2, 3, 4, 5], []), s([6], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], []), s([], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [6]), s([1], [2, 3, 4, 5], [6]), s([], [2, 3, 4, 5], [1, 6]), s([2], [3, 4, 5], [1, 6]), s([1, 2], [3, 4, 5], [6]), s([2], [1, 3, 4, 5], [6]), s([], [1, 3, 4, 5], [2, 6]), s([1], [3, 4, 5], [2, 6]), s([], [3, 4, 5], [1, 2, 6]), s([3], [4, 5], [1, 2, 6]), s([1, 3], [4, 5], [2, 6]), s([3], [1, 4, 5], [2, 6]), s([2, 3], [1, 4, 5], [6]), s([1, 2, 3], [4, 5], [6]), s([2, 3], [4, 5], [1, 6]), s([3], [2, 4, 5], [1, 6]), s([1, 3], [2, 4, 5], [6]), s([3], [1, 2, 4, 5], [6]), s([], [1, 2, 4, 5], [3, 6]), s([1], [2, 4, 5], [3, 6]), s([], [2, 4, 5], [1, 3, 6]), s([2], [4, 5], [1, 3, 6]), s([1, 2], [4, 5], [3, 6]), s([2], [1, 4, 5], [3, 6]), s([], [1, 4, 5], [2, 3, 6]), s([1], [4, 5], [2, 3, 6]), s([], [4, 5], [1, 2, 3, 6]), s([4], [5], [1, 2, 3, 6]), s([1, 4], [5], [2, 3, 6]), s([4], [1, 5], [2, 3, 6]), s([2, 4], [1, 5], [3, 6]), s([1, 2, 4], [5], [3, 6]), s([2, 4], [5], [1, 3, 6]), s([4], [2, 5], [1, 3, 6]), s([1, 4], [2, 5], [3, 6]), s([4], [1, 2, 5], [3, 6]), s([3, 4], [1, 2, 5], [6]), s([1, 3, 4], [2, 5], [6]), s([3, 4], [2, 5], [1, 6]), s([2, 3, 4], [5], [1, 6]), s([1, 2, 3, 4], [5], [6]), s([2, 3, 4], [1, 5], [6]), s([3, 4], [1, 5], [2, 6]), s([1, 3, 4], [5], [2, 6]), s([3, 4], [5], [1, 2, 6]), s([4], [3, 5], [1, 2, 6]), s([1, 4], [3, 5], [2, 6]), s([4], [1, 3, 5], [2, 6]), s([2, 4], [1, 3, 5], [6]), s([1, 2, 4], [3, 5], [6]), s([2, 4], [3, 5], [1, 6]), s([4], [2, 3, 5], [1, 6]), s([1, 4], [2, 3, 5], [6]), s([4], [1, 2, 3, 5], [6]), s([], [1, 2, 3, 5], [4, 6]), s([1], [2, 3, 5], [4, 6]), s([], [2, 3, 5], [1, 4, 6]), s([2], [3, 5], [1, 4, 6]), s([1, 2], [3, 5], [4, 6]), s([2], [1, 3, 5], [4, 6]), s([], [1, 3, 5], [2, 4, 6]), s([1], [3, 5], [2, 4, 6]), s([], [3, 5], [1, 2, 4, 6]), s([3], [5], [1, 2, 4, 6]), s([1, 3], [5], [2, 4, 6]), s([3], [1, 5], [2, 4, 6]), s([2, 3], [1, 5], [4, 6]), s([1, 2, 3], [5], [4, 6]), s([2, 3], [5], [1, 4, 6]), s([3], [2, 5], [1, 4, 6]), s([1, 3], [2, 5], [4, 6]), s([3], [1, 2, 5], [4, 6]), s([], [1, 2, 5], [3, 4, 6]), s([1], [2, 5], [3, 4, 6]), s([], [2, 5], [1, 3, 4, 6]), s([2], [5], [1, 3, 4, 6]), s([1, 2], [5], [3, 4, 6]), s([2], [1, 5], [3, 4, 6]), s([], [1, 5], [2, 3, 4, 6]), s([1], [5], [2, 3, 4, 6]), s([], [5], [1, 2, 3, 4, 6]), s([5], [], [1, 2, 3, 4, 6]), s([1, 5], [], [2, 3, 4, 6]), s([5], [1], [2, 3, 4, 6]), s([2, 5], [1], [3, 4, 6]), s([1, 2, 5], [], [3, 4, 6]), s([2, 5], [], [1, 3, 4, 6]), s([5], [2], [1, 3, 4, 6]), s([1, 5], [2], [3, 4, 6]), s([5], [1, 2], [3, 4, 6]), s([3, 5], [1, 2], [4, 6]), s([1, 3, 5], [2], [4, 6]), s([3, 5], [2], [1, 4, 6]), s([2, 3, 5], [], [1, 4, 6]), s([1, 2, 3, 5], [], [4, 6]), s([2, 3, 5], [1], [4, 6]), s([3, 5], [1], [2, 4, 6]), s([1, 3, 5], [], [2, 4, 6]), s([3, 5], [], [1, 2, 4, 6]), s([5], [3], [1, 2, 4, 6]), s([1, 5], [3], [2, 4, 6]), s([5], [1, 3], [2, 4, 6]), s([2, 5], [1, 3], [4, 6]), s([1, 2, 5], [3], [4, 6]), s([2, 5], [3], [1, 4, 6]), s([5], [2, 3], [1, 4, 6]), s([1, 5], [2, 3], [4, 6]), s([5], [1, 2, 3], [4, 6]), s([4, 5], [1, 2, 3], [6]), s([1, 4, 5], [2, 3], [6]), s([4, 5], [2, 3], [1, 6]), s([2, 4, 5], [3], [1, 6]), s([1, 2, 4, 5], [3], [6]), s([2, 4, 5], [1, 3], [6]), s([4, 5], [1, 3], [2, 6]), s([1, 4, 5], [3], [2, 6]), s([4, 5], [3], [1, 2, 6]), s([3, 4, 5], [], [1, 2, 6]), s([1, 3, 4, 5], [], [2, 6]), s([3, 4, 5], [1], [2, 6]), s([2, 3, 4, 5], [1], [6]), s([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [], [6]), s([2, 3, 4, 5], [], [1, 6]), s([3, 4, 5], [2], [1, 6]), s([1, 3, 4, 5], [2], [6]), s([3, 4, 5], [1, 2], [6]), s([4, 5], [1, 2], [3, 6]), s([1, 4, 5], [2], [3, 6]), s([4, 5], [2], [1, 3, 6]), s([2, 4, 5], [], [1, 3, 6]), s([1, 2, 4, 5], [], [3, 6]), s([2, 4, 5], [1], [3, 6]), s([4, 5], [1], [2, 3, 6]), s([1, 4, 5], [], [2, 3, 6]), s([4, 5], [], [1, 2, 3, 6]), s([5], [4], [1, 2, 3, 6]), s([1, 5], [4], [2, 3, 6]), s([5], [1, 4], [2, 3, 6]), s([2, 5], [1, 4], [3, 6]), s([1, 2, 5], [4], [3, 6]), s([2, 5], [4], [1, 3, 6]), s([5], [2, 4], [1, 3, 6]), s([1, 5], [2, 4], [3, 6]), s([5], [1, 2, 4], [3, 6]), s([3, 5], [1, 2, 4], [6]), s([1, 3, 5], [2, 4], [6]), s([3, 5], [2, 4], [1, 6]), s([2, 3, 5], [4], [1, 6]), s([1, 2, 3, 5], [4], [6]), s([2, 3, 5], [1, 4], [6]), s([3, 5], [1, 4], [2, 6]), s([1, 3, 5], [4], [2, 6]), s([3, 5], [4], [1, 2, 6]), s([5], [3, 4], [1, 2, 6]), s([1, 5], [3, 4], [2, 6]), s([5], [1, 3, 4], [2, 6]), s([2, 5], [1, 3, 4], [6]), s([1, 2, 5], [3, 4], [6]), s([2, 5], [3, 4], [1, 6]), s([5], [2, 3, 4], [1, 6]), s([1, 5], [2, 3, 4], [6]), s([5], [1, 2, 3, 4], [6]), s([], [1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6]), s([1], [2, 3, 4], [5, 6]), s([], [2, 3, 4], [1, 5, 6]), s([2], [3, 4], [1, 5, 6]), s([1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6]), s([2], [1, 3, 4], [5, 6]), s([], [1, 3, 4], [2, 5, 6]), s([1], [3, 4], [2, 5, 6]), s([], [3, 4], [1, 2, 5, 6]), s([3], [4], [1, 2, 5, 6]), s([1, 3], [4], [2, 5, 6]), s([3], [1, 4], [2, 5, 6]), s([2, 3], [1, 4], [5, 6]), s([1, 2, 3], [4], [5, 6]), s([2, 3], [4], [1, 5, 6]), s([3], [2, 4], [1, 5, 6]), s([1, 3], [2, 4], [5, 6]), s([3], [1, 2, 4], [5, 6]), s([], [1, 2, 4], [3, 5, 6]), s([1], [2, 4], [3, 5, 6]), s([], [2, 4], [1, 3, 5, 6]), s([2], [4], [1, 3, 5, 6]), s([1, 2], [4], [3, 5, 6]), s([2], [1, 4], [3, 5, 6]), s([], [1, 4], [2, 3, 5, 6]), s([1], [4], [2, 3, 5, 6]), s([], [4], [1, 2, 3, 5, 6]), s([4], [], [1, 2, 3, 5, 6]), s([1, 4], [], [2, 3, 5, 6]), s([4], [1], [2, 3, 5, 6]), s([2, 4], [1], [3, 5, 6]), s([1, 2, 4], [], [3, 5, 6]), s([2, 4], [], [1, 3, 5, 6]), s([4], [2], [1, 3, 5, 6]), s([1, 4], [2], [3, 5, 6]), s([4], [1, 2], [3, 5, 6]), s([3, 4], [1, 2], [5, 6]), s([1, 3, 4], [2], [5, 6]), s([3, 4], [2], [1, 5, 6]), s([2, 3, 4], [], [1, 5, 6]), s([1, 2, 3, 4], [], [5, 6]), s([2, 3, 4], [1], [5, 6]), s([3, 4], [1], [2, 5, 6]), s([1, 3, 4], [], [2, 5, 6]), s([3, 4], [], [1, 2, 5, 6]), s([4], [3], [1, 2, 5, 6]), s([1, 4], [3], [2, 5, 6]), s([4], [1, 3], [2, 5, 6]), s([2, 4], [1, 3], [5, 6]), s([1, 2, 4], [3], [5, 6]), s([2, 4], [3], [1, 5, 6]), s([4], [2, 3], [1, 5, 6]), s([1, 4], [2, 3], [5, 6]), s([4], [1, 2, 3], [5, 6]), s([], [1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]), s([1], [2, 3], [4, 5, 6]), s([], [2, 3], [1, 4, 5, 6]), s([2], [3], [1, 4, 5, 6]), s([1, 2], [3], [4, 5, 6]), s([2], [1, 3], [4, 5, 6]), s([], [1, 3], [2, 4, 5, 6]), s([1], [3], [2, 4, 5, 6]), s([], [3], [1, 2, 4, 5, 6]), s([3], [], [1, 2, 4, 5, 6]), s([1, 3], [], [2, 4, 5, 6]), s([3], [1], [2, 4, 5, 6]), s([2, 3], [1], [4, 5, 6]), s([1, 2, 3], [], [4, 5, 6]), s([2, 3], [], [1, 4, 5, 6]), s([3], [2], [1, 4, 5, 6]), s([1, 3], [2], [4, 5, 6]), s([3], [1, 2], [4, 5, 6]), s([], [1, 2], [3, 4, 5, 6]), s([1], [2], [3, 4, 5, 6]), s([], [2], [1, 3, 4, 5, 6]), s([2], [], [1, 3, 4, 5, 6]), s([1, 2], [], [3, 4, 5, 6]), s([2], [1], [3, 4, 5, 6]), s([], [1], [2, 3, 4, 5, 6]), s([1], [], [2, 3, 4, 5, 6]), s([], [], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6])]
```

In SWI-Prolog, one needs to hit <kbd>W</kbd> you ask the interactive shell to [print the full list](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8231762/67579).

Comment: I made a traverse predicate that should avoid repeats, but it gives me weird results and I can't understand why. It won't let me format code properly in the comments so I edited my original post with the traverse predicate, along with the change state code. Do you by any chance see whats wrong?

Comment: @Intellects: I think you defined a bit too much state transitions, the final code should have six clauses like the last code fragment.

Comment: The state transitions cover every possible transition, if I use just what you provided it doesn't work. There needs to be 12 state transitions because there's 3 towers. What I used covers from A->B, A->C, B->A, B->C, C->A, C->B, covers those transitions whether it's transfering to an empty stack or non-empty stack.

Comment: @Intellects: no six, since the empty stack/non empty stack distinction is abandoned with the last edit.

Comment: You're correct just realized this, cut down on some lines but still get more or less the same results: https://gyazo.com/82a1e333a7e61a0c344bed6d3b82a452. Once it pops those out it just keeps going forever and doesn't pop out any additional answers.

Comment: @Intellects: when I run the above locally (with a `[s(..)]` as initial visit, so a *list* of `s(..)`, not just `s(..)`), it keeps providing solutions.