# How might I get all the answers noninteractively without receiving duplicates?

Tags: prolog, swi-prolog, non-interactive

Inspired by [this worthy answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54245495/11422610) to a similar problem, I decided to use `fail` in the following code in order to get all the answers:

```
:-discontiguous(a/1),
discontiguous(aOnly/1),
discontiguous(dark_eyes/1),
discontiguous(pretty_face/1),
discontiguous(pigmented/1),
discontiguous(bleached_a/1).


a(adriana_chechik).
a(alysa_gap).
a(anna_de_ville).
dark_eyes(anna_de_ville).
pigmented(anna_de_ville).
a(aurora_jolie).
aOnly(aurora_jolie).
dark_eyes(aurora_jolie).
pretty_face(aurora_jolie).
pigmented(aurora_jolie).

dark_eyes(autumn_falls).
pretty_face(autumn_falls).
bleached_a(autumn_falls).
a(casey_calvert).
dark_eyes(casey_calvert).
pretty_face(casey_calvert).
pigmented(casey_calvert).
a(dahlia_sky).
a(dominica_lito).
dark_eyes(ella_knox).
pretty_face(ella_knox).
pigmented(ella_knox).
a(holly_hendrix).
dark_eyes(holly_hendrix).
pigmented(holly_hendrix).
a(isabella_clark).
dark_eyes(jade_kush).
pretty_face(jade_kush).
a(juelz_ventura).
dark_eyes(kapri_styles).
pigmented(kapri_styles).
dark_eyes(kristina_milan).
pretty_face(kristina_milan).
a(kylie_sinner).
aOnly(kylie_sinner).
dark_eyes(kylie_sinner).
pretty_face(kylie_sinner).
a(leigh_raven).
dark_eyes(leigh_raven).
pretty_face(leigh_raven).
dark_eyes(maserati).
pretty_face(maserati).
dark_eyes(miosotis).
pretty_face(miosotis).
dark_eyes(scarlett_bloom).
pretty_face(scarlett_bloom).
pigmented(scarlett_bloom).
pigmented(sheena_shaw).
dark_eyes(sofia_rose).
pretty_face(sofia_rose).
a(teanna_trump).
dark_eyes(teanna_trump).
pigmented(teanna_trump).
a(veronica_avluv).
a(yudi_pineda).
dark_eyes(yudi_pineda).
pretty_face(yudi_pineda).

:- initialization main.
main:-

a(X),
pretty_face(X),
print(X), nl,
fail.
```

Now, the issue that still remains is that the output to the command `swipl -q -s /home/jim/CS/SoftwareDevelopment/MySoftware/Racket/porn/females-by-Racket.pl -g main` (where `females-by-Racket.pl` is the file with the above code) looks like so:

```
aurora_jolie
casey_calvert
kylie_sinner
leigh_raven
yudi_pineda
Warning: /home/jim/CS/SoftwareDevelopment/MySoftware/Racket/porn/females-by-Racket.pl:68: Initialization goal failed
aurora_jolie
casey_calvert
kylie_sinner
leigh_raven
yudi_pineda
```

My fix for this is `swipl -q -s /home/jim/CS/SoftwareDevelopment/MySoftware/Racket/porn/females-by-Racket.pl -g main 2>/dev/null|sort -u` where the warning is redirected to `/dev/null` and the duplicate answers are removed with `sort -u`.

**1.** Why does my code produce duplicate answers?

**2.** Is it doable to accomplish what I did by appending `2>/dev/null|sort -u`  to the command but only do it within Prolog? I.e. without modifying the output afterwards with other tools.

Please let any interactive solutions that involve REPL be outside of the scope of this question.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You shouldn't use the `:-initialization main.` directive in your example, as you are already using main as the goal to execute.

So to answer your first question, it is giving you duplicate answers because the goal is called twice. First due to the initialization directive and then due to the target goal itself.

To avoid the initialization goal fail you may add another clause to main that always succeeds, so it would look like this:

```
main:-
  a(X),
  pretty_face(X),
  print(X), nl,
  fail.
main.
```

Comment: Thanks. When I skip the last line from your code, i.e. `main.` than it works as I intended. Otherwise it stays in the REPL.

Comment: You may also change the last clause to explicitly `halt` the program, i.e. `main:- halt.`, Otherwise it seems to exit due to the procedure failing.

Comment: Many times no. This is a silly way to do it. Sorry for the downvote. You are fixing the problem in the wrong place. OP was already on the right track before you took them for a ride.