# Generate all words of length N and form a list with them in Prolog

Tags: prolog, backtracking

Given the letters [a, b, c] generate the list containing all the words of length N, formed out of this letters. 
For example:

```
?- generate(2, L).
```

should output:

> L = [aa, ab, ac, ba, bb, bc, ca, cb, cc].

At first, this seemed like a pretty simple problem, but I've discovered that none of my implementations work.

This is the second implementation, the one that kind of works.

```
letter(X) :- member(X, [a, b, c]).

generateWord(0, []) :- !.
generateWord(N, [H|T]) :-
    letter(H), 
    NextN is N - 1,
    generateWord(NextN, T).

generateAtomicWord(N, Word) :-
    generateWord(N, WList),
    atomic_list_concat(WList, Word).

maxSolutions(N, R) :- R is N ** 3.

generate(N, CurrentList, ResultList) :-
    maxSolutions(N, R), 
    length(CurrentList, L),
    L =:= R, 
    append(CurrentList, [], ResultList), !.
generate(N, CurrentList, ResultList) :-
    generateAtomicWord(N, NewWord),
    \+ member(NewWord, CurrentList),
    append(CurrentList, [NewWord], NewList),
    generate(N, NewList, ResultList).

generate(N, ResultList) :- 
    generate(N, [], ResultList).
```

It *kind of works* because when given **N = 3** the program outputs:

> L = [aaa, aab, aac, aba, abb, abc, aca, acb, acc|...]

My first implementation is different, but I can't make it work on any case.

```
letter(X) :- member(X, [a, b, c]).

generateWord(0, []) :- !.
generateWord(N, [H|T]) :-
    letter(H), 
    NextN is N - 1,
    generateWord(NextN, T), !.

generateAtomicWord(N, Word) :-
    generateWord(N, WList),
    atomic_list_concat(WList, Word).

maxSolutions(N, R) :- R is N ** 3.

generate(N, [H]) :- generateAtomicWord(N, H).
generate(N, [H|T]) :- 
    generate(N, T),
    length(T, TailLen), 
    maxSolutions(N, M), 
    (TailLen =:= M -> !; 
        generateAtomicWord(N, H),
        \+ member(H, T)).
```

This one just outputs:

> L = [aa]

and when requested for the rest of the solutions it cycles.

The problem must be solved without using predicates such as:

> findall, findnsol, bagof, setof, etc...

that find all the solutions.

I've added the tag **backtracking** because it does resemble a backtracking problem, but I've no idea what a standard implementation might look like in Prolog.

Comment: Please provide more information on the concrete context of this exercise.

Answer (score 0):

> It kind of works because when given N = 3 the program outputs:
>
> ```
> L = [aaa, aab, aac, aba, abb, abc, aca, acb, acc|...]
> ```

That is not an error, that is the Prolog interpreter that *displays* the list in a shorter way. If you hit <kbd>w</kbd> when it shows the output, it will show the full list. For more information see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20922068/67579).

That being said, you make it too hard. You can first make a predicate that will unify a variable with all possible atoms:

```
letter(X) :- member(X, [a, b, c]).

word(0, []).
word(N, [C|W]) :-
    N > 0,
    N1 is N-1,
    letter(C),
    word(N1, W).
```

Now we can generate all possibilities with [**`findall/3`** [swi-doc]](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=findall/3), and use for example [**`maplist/3`** [swi-doc]](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=maplist/3) with [**`atomic_list_concat/2`**](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=atomic_list_concat/2) to convert the list to a single atom:

```
words(N, L) :-
    findall(W, word(N, W), Ws),
    maplist(atomic_list_concat, Ws, L).
```

For example:

```
?- words(0, L).
L = [''].

?- words(1, L).
L = [a, b, c].

?- words(2, L).
L = [aa, ab, ac, ba, bb, bc, ca, cb, cc].

?- words(3, L).
L = [aaa, aab, aac, aba, abb, abc, aca, acb, acc|...].
```

We can generate a list of lists ourselves by updating a "difference" list until all possible words are generated:

```
wordlist(N, L) :-
    wordlist(N, [], L, []).

wordlist(0, R, [W|T], T) :-
    reverse(R, W),
    !.
wordlist(N, C, L, T) :-
    N > 0,
    N1 is N-1,
    wordfold([a,b,c], N1, C, L, T).

wordfold([], _, _, L, L).
wordfold([C|CS], N1, CT, L, T) :-
    wordlist(N1, [C|CT], L, L2),
    wordfold(CS, N1, CT, L2, T).
```

For example:

```
?- wordlist(0, L).
L = [[]].

?- wordlist(1, L).
L = [[a], [b], [c]].

?- wordlist(2, L).
L = [[a, a], [a, b], [a, c], [b, a], [b, b], [b, c], [c, a], [c|...], [...|...]].
```

You then still need to perform `atomic_list_concat` on it. I leave that as an exercise.

Comment: I forgot to specify, but I'm not allowed to use **findAll**.

Comment: @CosminStoian: that's not that much of a problem. Try to make something that can collect the results :)

Comment: That's what I've tried to do in my first implementation, but I absolutely suck at prolog. I will try some more with your implementation. Thank you!

Comment: Without findAll is there any other way of stoping executing the program besides manually calculating the number of maximum solutions?

Comment: @CosminStoian: yes, you can use a difference-list that you build up by passing through the possible solutions.